# Loop by category and meta_key

Tags: categories, loop

I'm trying to "mount" a loop for `category.php` in which it is based on the current category and meta key.

But the loop insists on showing posts from another category

```
global $taxonomy,
        $term;

$cats       = get_the_category();
$newQuery   = new WP_Query( array( 
    'cat'           => $cats[0]->term_id,
    'meta_key'      => 'premium_model',
    'meta_value'    => true,
    'posts_per_page'=> 24, 
    'orderby'       => 'rand'                             
) );  

if( $newQuery->have_posts() ) {

    while( $newQuery->have_posts() ) { 

        $newQuery->the_post(); 
        // Post Here
    }
}
```

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) will retrieve the category of current loop item. In your case, it's probably the last post of your main archive query.

To get the category of currently displayed category in the archive page, you can use `get_queried_object_id()`:

```
// Check if this is a category archive
if ( is_category() ) {

    // Get the current category ID
    $category_id = get_queried_object_id();
}
```